# Sub-classes access each other's member functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on a project that had been thought out, rather poorly. I have subclasses that access each other's member functions. Here's the situation:

```
class A {
public:
    class B;
    class C;
};

class A::B {
public:
    void f() {
        C:g();
    }
}
class A::C {
public:
    void g() {
        B:f();
    }
}
```

This code, obviously, runs into various errors which is too much list here. My question is, what is the solution to such a situation? Is it inheritance? If so, how? Is there any other way for me to preserve the "interplaying"-nature of classes B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `C:g()` --> `C::g()`, `B:f()` --> `B::f()`

You can not call member function without object unless these member functions are static.
Probably a pointer to each other may resolve your issue?
*I introduce pointer is because otherwise I need to write something to help with circular include issue.*  :)

```
#include <memory>

class A::B {
public:
    void f() {
        c_->g();
    }
  std::unique_ptr<C> c_;
}
class A::C {
public:
    void g() {
        b_->f();
    }
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
}
```

Comment: Typo. My bad. Apologies. But the solution to this? Inheritance?

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks a ton. BTW (for others), works only with C++-11.
Compile with 
    -std=gnu++11

Comment: std::unique_ptr is form C++11, you could use std::shared_ptr from tr1 if  you don't use C++11

Answer (score -1):

move method definitions out of class declarations, so both classes will be declared and their methods are visible to each other

Comment: I considered that, but those functions access the private variables of those classes :(

Comment: so what? you just need a full class definition to access that members... and yes, you need an instance to access function-members as @billz suggest